# SQL Alchemy doesnt append existing table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

Im just trying to upload the table to company server however after first upload it doesn't neither append nor replace in same table.

```
#Import Libraries# 
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sal
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
#SQL Alchemy Connection String

engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://GRATHDB03\REPLICA/DATAWRHS-TRAINING?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?Trusted_Connection=yes',
                           fast_executemany=True
                          )
#Read and Upload the file
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\ehan\Downloads\results-survey177217 (1).csv')
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('/', '').str.replace('?','').str.replace('&','').str.replace(';','').str.replace(',','').str.replace(':','').str.replace('Kindly rate your trainer on the following catagories','')
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('[','').str.replace(']','')
df['Date submitted']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date submitted'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date started']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date started'],dayfirst=True)
df.to_sql('limesurveytest3', engine, index=False, if_exists='append',schema='[dbo]')
```

and here is the error.

(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'limesurveytest3' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: Try `schema='dbo'` instead of `schema='[dbo]'`

Answer (score 1):

Worked without []

```
df.to_sql('limesurveytest3', engine, index=False, if_exists='append',schema='dbo')
```